# GMock testing destructor calls

Tags: googlemock

I've read the section in the gmock cookbook on [Mocking Destructors](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Destructors) but I'm having no luck getting it to work.  My code is almost exactly what the doc says:

```
class MockFoo : public Foo {
public:
    MockFoo() {}
    MOCK_METHOD0(destroyMockFoo, void());
    virtual ~MockFoo() { destroyMockFoo(); }
};

TEST_F(DestructorTest, shouldFail) {
    MockFoo* foo = new MockFoo();
    EXPECT_CALL(*foo, destroyMockFoo());
}
```

But when I run the code, the test passes with no errors. I do get the error at the end of the test output about the leaked object:

```
DestructorTest.cpp:149: ERROR: this mock object (used in test DestructorTest.shouldFail) should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0x8178790.
ERROR: 1 leaked mock object found at program exit.
```

but this is not what I want nor is it what the doc says should happen.

So what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, necessarily. The problem here is that gmock expectations are verified in the destructor of the mock object, so if the destructor is never called, then the expectations are never verified. This is what's happening in your example.

The easy way to get around this is to explicitly verify the expectations on the mock:

```
Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(foo);
```

This will give you the behavior that you're looking for.

Comment: `VerifyAndClearExpectations`  will work but the correct behavior here, I think, is to simply delete the mock object at the end of the test.

Comment: That's also a possibility, though I'm assuming that the use case here is to transfer ownership of the mock object to some other class, and verify that the other class properly disposes of the mock. Deleting the mock at the end of the test wouldn't allow that type of verification.

Comment: Ian is right.  In my real test, ownership of the mock is being transferred and I wan to verify that the mock is really deleted.

Comment: If that component really deletes the mock, you won't see this error. If it does not and is expected to, that message have just caught a problem in that code. You just have to make sure that destructor of `Foo` is virtual.

Comment: I agree; it's unfortunate that this test passes. Based on my understanding, this is a limitation which stems from the way that mock objects are implemented. Given the current design (i.e. expectations are verified upon destruction of mock objects), I'm not sure if the 'correct' behavior is possible here. If you can think of a way to solve the problem, I'd love to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete foo object at the end of test so that it will not give object leak.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the post.  The point is that the test passes when it shouldn't.  Since the expectation isn't met, the test should fail. Mentioning the error message about the leaked object was just a side note.  As Ian pointed out, adding Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(foo) to the test makes it fail.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the memory leak message, you can test the return value of Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(foo) and delete the object explicitly if it false.